# TortoiseSVN not asking for authentication?

Tags: svn, authentication, tortoisesvn

I've setup a new SVN repository, running SVNServe, in the conf file, anon-access = none.

SVNServe faithfully does that correctly, but when I try to browse the repos using TortoiseSVN, it just says access is not allowed. Shouldn't it ask me for the user name and password instead?

How do I get TortoiseSVN to ask me for the login details?

Running SVN 1.5.6, TortoiseSVN 1.5.9

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should ask you automatically.  You're using the svn:// protocol, right?  Can you post your config?

Comment: Yeah, the other repos I setup did ask for it automatically, so I don't know why it doesn't for this one. The other repos was Apache though, this one is SVNServe. Yes I'm using svn://

Apart from the default comments, I only added this to config:
realm = Subversion Repository

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sorry, didn't uncomment following line in the config:

password-db = passwd

Comment: good it was solved :) - accept your own answer, so this this question appears as answered.

Comment: To clarify, config is svnserve.conf in repo/conf

Comment: @Robo where you have this "password-db = passwd " ?

Answer (score 25):

It probably has some authentication data saved, try:

right click->tortoise->settings->saved data->Authentication Data-Clear.

In some cases the "Clear"-Authentication data button remains disabled, then rename the folder in which the certificate is saved. Next time SVN will automatically ask for the password.

Comment: Nop...checked that, no authentication data saved. The Clear button is disabled.

Comment: This folder is `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using beanstalkapp.com and was able to resolve it by using http**s** instead of http when specifying the svn checkout url.

That's what I get for not copying and pasting.

Comment: I could have sworn I checked out using HTTPS from Google code, but apparently I didn't. Relocating the HTTP URL to HTTPS made TortoiseSVN start asking for credentials again.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add one extra solution that might be stopping TortoiseSVN from asking for authentication. I had the situation that a user could authenticate from other machines just fine, but on this one machine it would fail with a "Unexpected HTTP status 503 'Service Unavailable'" and not ask for authentication. The Tortoise Settings > Saved Data > Authentication Data was clear, we could delete the %APPDATA%\Roaming\subversion\ files to no avail. Turns out that at some point the user had tried to "fix" a problem by setting the network proxy.

- **Solution: Tortoise > Settings > Network > uncheck Enable Proxy Server**

Cheers, hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If the "Clear"-Authentication data button remains disabled, in spite of saving the certificate just rename the folder in which the certificate is saved. Next time SVN will automatically ask for the password.

Answer (score 0):

One think I just found, there was a -R in the svnserve config (read-only for all repos) put there on installation - a simple thing but this is all new to me...

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected through DirectAccess you should download the IPv6 version of TortoiseSVN.
You can find the latest version [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/).

It can be found under the folder *Version*/Application/ipv6

Answer (score 0):

Restart your System after update of Password. 
After restarting SVN will reconfigure itself and ask for authentication rather of using previous stored password

Answer (score 0):

Settings - Advanced - AllowAuthSave = true

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn your PC off and back on again if you change your Windows password for Tortoise SVN to work.  Clearing auth tokens does not work nor does reinstalling the software.  However a restart and relogin to the windows account did work.  I guess something to do with the way it integrates to your domain account. It did not ask for the new password after the reboot.