# How to set username/password to connect to Subversion repository in AnkhSVN in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, authentication, passwords, ankhsvn

I just installed AnkhSVN. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

There is an existing Subversion repository on a server that I access via SSL (ex: `https://svn.myserver.com/myrepository`).

In Visual Studio, I set my source control to "AnkhSVN - Subversion support to Visual Studio" in the tools/options menu.

In the "Add to Subversion" dialog, when I try to add my solution in the repository, I enter `https://svn.myserver.com/myrepository` in the "Repository URL" field.
Then, `https://svn.myserver.com` appears under "Subversion Repositories". 
When I select it, the "Create Folder..." button stays disabled and when I click OK, I get the message:

> Please select a valid location in the repository to add to.

I want to add my solution in `https://svn.myserver.com/myrepository/myfolder` but it doesn't seem to be possible.

What am I missing?

Also:
In Repository Explorer I add the url `https://svn.myserver.com/myrepository` and nothing happens. I cannot browse that repository. It looks like I cannot connect to the server.

I wonder why there's no popup asking me for authentication.

Does anybody know where to set username / password?

Answer (score 1):

Solutions:

- You can go to Tools - Options - Source Control - Subversion Environment - Authentication Cache to clear the cached username/passwords

or

- The authentication data is saved to the following directories

%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.ssl.server
%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple

Deleting all the files inside these folders will solve the problem. After deleting these files AnkhSVN will prompt you for username and password once again.

or

- From the file system right click->tortoise->settings->saved data->Authentication Data-Clear.

References:

http://www.nerdpad.com/how-to/clearing-ankhsvn-saved-username-password-authentication-data

[How to change SVN authentication details in AnkhSVN in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313747/how-to-change-svn-authentication-details-in-ankhsvn-in-visual-studio-2010)

[TortoiseSVN not asking for authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664761/tortoisesvn-not-asking-for-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the solution foldwr to repository(with the whole solution).There you will set the username and password. When opening Visual Studio, the ankhsvn should manage it automatically(with no credentials).