# AnkhSVN add-in for VS2010 not asking for username/password, so can't connect to server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

I've been using the AnkhSVN add-in with VS2010 on my main dev machine for a while, and can connect to both our company's SVN server, which is hosted by beanstalk, and also to a local one we have on the office network, which is running VisualSVN Server.

I just installed Win8 on my lap top, and have installed VS2010 and the AnkhSVN add-in (same version as on my dev machine). I can open a solution from the beanstalk URL no problem, but when I try to open one from the local SVN, nothing happens.

To be more precise, I go to File -> Subversion -> Open from Subversion, click the little blue globe icon next to the Url dropdown, enter the URL and click Finish and... nothing happens. I am left with the Open from Subversion window as it was before. I can still see the last repository opened.

Sometimes, it doesn't show me a repository when I open this window, and then when I try to connect to the local VisualSVN repository, I get a message saying http://10.0.0.100:8080/svn/TestProject'> but no indication as to why it couldn't connect.

I can paste the same URL into a web browser, and after entering my user name and password, it shows me the repository.

I suspect that the problem is that the VisualSVN server requires a user name and password, but the AnkhSVN add-in doesn't ask me for one. It did when I connected to beanstalk.

I found this SO post, [How to set username/password to connect to Subversion repository in AnkhSVN in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358297/how-to-set-username-password-to-connect-to-subversion-repository-in-ankhsvn-in-v) which suggests checking Tools - Options - Source Control - Subversion Environment - Authentication Cache, but that only shows the beanstalk one. If I delete that, I still can't connect to the local server, but can connect to beanstalk after entering my user name and password again.

I also checked in the Subversion folder under %APPDATA%\Roaming, but there wasn't anything in any of the four folders there.

Anyone any idea what I can do? The add-in prompts me for a user name and password when connecting to beanstalk, but not when connecting to the VisualSVN server.

Comment: Anyone? I'm completely stuck here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't get anywhere here, but I did discover that the VisualSVN add-in for VS connected fine, so will use that.